# Sending post in jsp frame src

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

How to send parameters of url as post method in frame of a JSP ?

In a frame set I have two frames which I need to send to same server but different parameters but due to security reasons I want to send these parameters in a POST request.

I have something like this :

```
<frame name="menuframe" src ="xyz?A="<%=a%>" scrolling="NO" noresize>
```

Now I want this A parameter to go as POST request and not travel in url. 
Can I do it somehow using this frame only or is there any alternative ?

Comment: I have something like this

Comment: <frame name="menuframe" src ="xyz?A="<%=a%>" scrolling="NO" noresize

Comment: Now I want this A parameter to go as post request and not travel in url. Can I do it somehow using this frame only or is there any alternative

Comment: **Short:** not possible - all URLs from attributes (like `src`, `href` etc.) are loaded using the GET method. **Long:** I could imagine some javascript workaround, loading the frame content via AJAX from the main HTML, anyway, that would be most probably a very dirty and hard to maintain solution.